# Converting SHA1 hash Hex string to decimals using objective C on iPhone

Tags: ios, sha1

I am a beginner to developing apps on the iPhone and I am trying to convert a 40 character SHA1 hash in hex to decimals. i have been looking around and the largest integer type in unsigned long long but it's not enough. I tried looking at **NSDecimalNumber** but it doesn't have Hex function.

Comment: You can use an array like "char c[]", "int i[]" or "long l[]" to store the SHA1.

Comment: I am able to store it as a string. I want to get decimal equivalent of  the SHA-1 hash.

Comment: what do you want to do with it at the end that requires decimal value?

Comment: The task is to get a series of numbers from the decimal value of the hash for identification purpose. For android, this can be achieved using bigintegers. In order to ensure parity between the 2 platform,  i hope to achieve it on the iPhone the same way i could do it on android.

Comment: If you take careful of your codes, you can just use string. I think you just want to use it for identification. Do you need any arithmetic on SHA1 string like the function of bitinteger ?

Comment: Yes I know that using string comparison is a possibility. There are some arithmetic done on the android platform and I do not wish to change that logic unless absolutely necessary. 

So conversion of a SHA1 hex string to decimals is not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess there is no way of doing so. I would have to change it to a string instead.